# Ceil a datetime to next quarter of an hour

Tags: python, datetime, ceil

Let's imagine this `datetime`

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 32, 16)
```

I'd like to ceil it to the next quarter of hour, in order to get

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 45)
```

I imagine something like

```
>>> quarter = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
>>> import math
>>> ceiled_dt = math.ceil(dt / quarter) * quarter
```

But of course, this does not work

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This one takes microseconds into account!

```
import math

def ceil_dt(dt):
    # how many secs have passed this hour
    nsecs = dt.minute*60 + dt.second + dt.microsecond*1e-6  
    # number of seconds to next quarter hour mark
    # Non-analytic (brute force is fun) way:  
    #   delta = next(x for x in xrange(0,3601,900) if x>=nsecs) - nsecs
    # analytic way:
    delta = math.ceil(nsecs / 900) * 900 - nsecs
    #time + number of seconds to quarter hour mark.
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(seconds=delta)

t1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 0)
assert ceil_dt(t1) == t1

t2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 1)
assert ceil_dt(t2) == datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 15)

t3 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 15)
assert ceil_dt(t3) == t3

t4 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 16)
assert ceil_dt(t4) == datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 30)

t5 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 30)
assert ceil_dt(t5) == t5

t6 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 31)
assert ceil_dt(t6) == datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 45)

t7 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 45)
assert ceil_dt(t7) == t7

t8 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 7, 46)
assert ceil_dt(t8) == datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 6, 8, 0)
```

Explanation of `delta`:

- 900 seconds is 15 minutes (a quarter of an hour *sans leap seconds which I don't think datetime handles...*)
- `nsecs / 900` is the number of quarter hour chunks that have transpired.  Taking the `ceil` of this rounds up the number of quarter hour chunks.
- Multiply the number of quarter hour chunks by 900 to figure out how many seconds have transpired in since the start of the hour after "rounding".

Comment: I tried it with 3600 instead of 900 and it's not working. It's adding 3600 even if the time is already rounded.

Comment: I'm thinking that I should have used `delta = math.ceil(nsecs / 900.) * 900.`

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
delta = math.ceil(nsecs / 900) * 900 - nsecs

Comment: @junebob -- Yes it should.  Previous revisions had it and somewhere along the way I managed to drop it for some reason.  I suppose I should probably write some unit-tests for this at some point ...

Comment: Good job!.......

Answer (score 19):

[@Mark Dickinson suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071384/python-ceil-a-datetime-to-next-quarter-of-an-hour/32657466#comment53190737_32657466) the best formula so far:

```
def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return dt + (datetime.min - dt) % delta
```

---

In Python 3, for an arbitrary time delta (not just 15 minutes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return datetime.min + math.ceil((dt - datetime.min) / delta) * delta

print(ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 32, 16), timedelta(minutes=15)))
# -> 2012-10-25 17:45:00
```

To avoid intermediate floats, `divmod()` could be used:

```
def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    q, r = divmod(dt - datetime.min, delta)
    return (datetime.min + (q + 1)*delta) if r else dt
```

Example:

```
>>> ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 32, 16), timedelta(minutes=15))
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 45)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.min, datetime.resolution) 
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.min, 2*datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max, datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max, 2*datetime.resolution)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in ceil_dt
OverflowError: date value out of range
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.min+datetime.resolution, datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.min+datetime.resolution, 2*datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max-datetime.resolution, datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999998)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max-datetime.resolution, 2*datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999998)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max-2*datetime.resolution, datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999997)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max-2*datetime.resolution, 2*datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999998)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max-timedelta(1), datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 30, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max-timedelta(1), 2*datetime.resolution)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 0, 0)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.min, datetime.max-datetime.min)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> ceil_dt(datetime.max, datetime.max-datetime.min)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

Comment: If you're restricting to Python 3, then the simpler expression `dt + (datetime.min - dt) % delta` also works.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: yes. It does work on CPython (for all the examples in the answer). You should post: `def ceil_dt(dt, delta): return dt + (datetime.min - dt) % delta` as an answer.

Comment: This ceil_dt function does not work correctly with fractional sections (ie, rounding to the nearest 60/22 = 2.727273 seconds). I think this is due to the floating point precision when calculating back all the way to Epoch. Otherwise, fabulous!

Comment: @BrianBienvenu: could you provide a specific example `result = ceil_dt(dt, delta)` what are `dt`, `delta`, `result` in your case? What `result` have you expected instead?

Comment: @jfs: try this:

`print(ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 32, 1), timedelta(seconds=60/7))); print(ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 18, 32, 1), timedelta(seconds=60/7))); print(ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 19, 32, 1), timedelta(seconds=60/7)))`

I get: 
`2012-10-25 17:32:02.910426`
`2012-10-25 18:32:02.910606`
`2012-10-25 19:32:02.910786`

All of these should logically show a response of *:32:08.571429, however they don't. Further, they aren't consistent. If you run the above code with `seconds=60/6` (or 10), then you get the expected rounding to `*:32:10`.

Comment: @BrianBienvenu what is your use case? I would try `delta` values that are multiples of microseconds (not tested)

Comment: If you want to round down, I answered this on a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65313918/6794536

Comment: Can you make take care for cases that microseconds!=0 please?

Comment: @ChrisP `microseconds!=0` is  supported (just look at the REPL examples in the answer)

Answer (score 9):

```
def ceil(dt):
    if dt.minute % 15 or dt.second:
        return dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15 - dt.minute % 15,
                                       seconds = -(dt.second % 60))
    else:
        return dt
```

This gives you:

```
>>> ceil(datetime.datetime(2012,10,25, 17,45))
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 45)
>>> ceil(datetime.datetime(2012,10,25, 17,45,1))
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 25, 18, 0)
>>> ceil(datetime.datetime(2012,12,31,23,59,0))
datetime.datetime(2013,1,1,0,0)
```

Comment: This is a little funky because you operate on `dt` in place, but then you return it.  from an API perspective, It seems like you should either do one or the other ... (Also, this doesn't take `microseconds` into account)

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks for the comment, you're right of course. I did ignore microseconds because the OP was constructing his datetimes without them. But of course that may be a problem if that's not his real-world use case.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm happy enough with it now that you fixed the API stuff (+1)

Comment: I also like that you said "you're right *of course*".  While I have a nasty habit of assuming I'm always right, I don't think that other people usually agree O:^)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to calculate correct minutes and add them in datetime object after setting minutes, seconds to zero

```py
import datetime

def quarter_datetime(dt):
    minute = (dt.minute//15+1)*15
    return dt.replace(minute=0, second=0)+datetime.timedelta(minutes=minute)

for minute in [12, 22, 35, 52]:
    print quarter_datetime(datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, minute, 16))
```

It works for all cases:

```
2012-10-25 17:15:00
2012-10-25 17:30:00
2012-10-25 17:45:00
2012-10-25 18:00:00
```

Comment: This is a duplicated of Pierre GM's answer, except yours will only work as expected in Python 2.x due to the use of ``/`` over ``//``.

Comment: @Lattyware I think we posted it at same time + now it is not same as I have fixed a bug, and his solution has defect

Comment: Great, although I'd note the use of ``/`` over ``//`` is still sub-optimal. Also, SO notifies you when someone else posts an answer, it's worth looking before you post yours to check you are not duplicating an answer.

Comment: I thin we had 15 secs difference and I did not see any other post

Answer (score 2):

The [formula proposed here by @Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32657466) worked beautifully, but I needed a solution that also handled timezones and Daylight Savings Time (DST).

Using `pytz`, I arrived at:

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def datetime_ceiling(dt, delta):
    # Preserve original timezone info
    original_tz = dt.tzinfo
    if original_tz:
        # If the original was timezone aware, translate to UTC.
        # This is necessary because datetime math does not take
        # DST into account, so first we normalize the datetime...
        dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
        # ... and then make it timezone naive
        dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
    # We only do math on a timezone naive object, which allows
    # us to pass naive objects directly to the function
    dt = dt + ((datetime.min - dt) % delta)
    if original_tz:
        # If the original was tz aware, we make the result aware...
        dt = pytz.UTC.localize(dt)
        # ... then translate it from UTC back its original tz.
        # This translation applies appropriate DST status.
        dt = dt.astimezone(original_tz)
    return dt
```

A nearly identical `floor` function can be made by changing one line of code:

```py
def datetime_floor(dt, delta):
    ...
    dt = dt - ((datetime.min - dt) % delta)
    ...
```

The following datetime is three minutes before the transition from DST back to Standard Time (STD):

```py
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 1, 57, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

Assuming the above as `dt`, we can round down to the nearest five minute increment using our floor function:

```
>>> datetime_floor(dt, timedelta(minutes=5))
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 1, 55, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

The timezone and relationship to DST is preserved. (The same would be true for the ceiling function.)

On this date DST will end at 2 am, at which point the time will "roll back" to 1am STD. If we use our ceiling function to round up from 1:57am DST, we should *not* end up at 2am DST, but rather at 1:00am STD, which is the result we get:

```
>>> datetime_ceiling(dt, timedelta(minutes=5))
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
```

Comment: I believe the floor function should read `dt = dt - ((dt - datetime.min) % delta)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code working with any periods:

```
def floorDT(dt, secperiod):
    tstmp = dt.timestamp()
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        math.floor(tstmp/secperiod)*secperiod).astimezone().astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)


def ceilDT(dt, secperiod):
    tstmp = dt.timestamp()
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        math.ceil(tstmp/secperiod)*secperiod).astimezone().astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Note: we must use astimezone().astimezone() trick else it uses local timezone during converting from timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example by Mark Dickinson's, here is an enhanced `datetime` round up function that also preserves the timezone information of the original timestamp (both naive and timezone aware):

```py
def round_datetime_up(
        ts: datetime.datetime,
        delta: datetime.timedelta,
        offset: datetime.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=0)) -> datetime.datetime:
    """Snap to next available timedelta.

    Preserve any timezone info on `ts`.

    If we are at the the given exact delta, then do not round, only add offset.

    :param ts: Timestamp we want to round
    :param delta: Our snap grid
    :param offset: Add a fixed time offset at the top of rounding
    :return: Rounded up datetime
    """
    rounded = ts + (datetime.datetime.min.replace(tzinfo=ts.tzinfo) - ts) % delta
    return rounded + offset
```

See [full code](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/blob/master/tradeexecutor/strategy/tick.py) and [tests](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/blob/master/tests/test_tick_size.py).