# Update QWidget every minutes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Is their a way possible to update a Qwidget in PyQT4 every  15 minutes ? I know their is something like a Qtimer but is it also possible to make a QWidget update itself at a specific time,for example 00h00 00h15 00h30 00h45 01h00,... . So is their a way to make the Qtimer depend on the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QTimer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html) class has a [`setInterval`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html#setInterval) method. You can utilize this to change the wait time on the fly. As a short example, this block of code will show the current second. However, if the second is a multiple of 10 it will wait 5 seconds before starting again:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from time import strftime

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Time)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.display(strftime("%S"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.lcd)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,100)

    def Time(self):
        if int(strftime("%S")) % 10 == 0:
            self.timer.setInterval(5000)
        else:
            self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.lcd.display(strftime("%S"))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(This was modified slightly from a [tutorial](http://thecodeinn.blogspot.com/2013/07/tutorial-pyqt-digital-clock.html) showing how to build a digital clock)

It looks like this for 4 consecutive changes of the display:

[image: Seconds]

---

For your particular problem, when you start the application, you can find how long it is until the next quarter hour via a function like is presented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071613/189134):

```
def next_quarter_hour(self):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    nsecs = dt.minute*60+dt.second+dt.microsecond*1e-6  
    delta = (nsecs//900)*900+900-nsecs
    return delta * 1000.0
```

This would change the following:

```
def initUI(self):
    ...
    self.timer.start(next_qt_hour)
    ...

def Time(self):
    if int(strftime("%M")) % 15 == 0:
        self.timer.setInterval(900000)
    self.lcd.display(strftime("%M"))
```

Use this to set your first interval. Then once that timer has been exhausted, reset your interval to 15 minutes.