# python Trying to make minutes go to the nearest quarter

Tags: python, time

```
Hours= int(input("What Hour is it?"))
Minutes= int(input("What Minute is it?"))
if Hours<12:
    print(Hours , (':'), Minutes)
elif Hours>12:
    print(Hours-12 ,(':'), Minutes)
```

I'm trying to make the following code go to the closest quarter/15 minutes but don't know how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `(round(Minutes/15.)*15)%60` ? Though incase its `60` you would need to add `1` to Hours as well.

Comment: related: [Python - Ceil a datetime to next quarter of an hour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13071384/4279)

Comment: @AnandSKumar: you might also need to change pm to am and in reverse.

Comment: @JFSebastian , but OP himself has not added it.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: a question may contain any number of bugs; an answer should generally avoid introducing bugs.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This is/was not a complete answer, that is why its a comment (its just a kind of hint towards how to get an answer).

Comment: @AnandSKumar: my comment is an addition to your comment. It is not a critique.

Answer (score 0):

try rouning you minutes to 15:

```
Hours= int(input("What Hour is it?"))
Minutes= int(input("What Minute is it?"))
if Hours<12:
    print(Hours , (':'), Minutes)
elif Hours>12:
    print(Hours-12 ,(':'), Minutes)
Minutes= round(Minutes/15)*15
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your solution if you are not change minute variable then how u can expect that it set to the nearest quater.
SO you just need to add 1 line which alter minute

for getting answer like 1st quater,2nd quater,3rd quater or 4th quater :

```
minute = (minute+1)%15
```

for getting answer like 15min,30min,45min,60min :

```
minute = ((minute+1)%15)*15
```