# how to get 20 mins before the last 10th minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

So I need to calculate 20 minutes before the last 10 mins.
EG if it's currently 13:07, the time I need is 12:40

So from my research, I think I need to find the last 10th (or 0th) minute of the hour, then minus 20 minutes from that.

[I found an answer to finding the next 10th minute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32657466)

so I adjusted the code to find the last 10th minute, and then simply "- datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)"

```
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def ceil_dt(dt, delta):
    return datetime.min + math.ceil((dt - datetime.min) / delta) * delta

print(ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 2, 16), timedelta(minutes=-10))) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)
```

But it gives me the following exception

```
2012-10-25 17:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Pythong/test", line 7, in <module>
    print(ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 2, 16), timedelta(minutes=-10))) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. First, you `import timedelta` and then call `datetime.timedelta`, when you should call `timedelta` directly. Second, your close parenthesis for `print` is misplaced. So this will work:

```
ceil_dt(datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 2, 16), timedelta(minutes=-10)) - timedelta(minutes=20)
```

But you can just use:

```
dt = datetime(2012, 10, 25, 17, 2, 16)
res = dt - timedelta(minutes=dt.minute+20)
```

Answer (score 1):

The import problem is with `datetime.timedelta`. As you import like `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`, so `datetime` in the following code is actually `datetime.datetime` class.

There're two solutions: either you change `datetime.timedelta` to `timedelta`, or you change the way you import to `import datetime` and then change `datetime` in your code to `datetime.datetime`. I'd recommend the first one as it is simpler.

The fact that `datetime` package and `datetime` class have the same name is making things a bit complicated. You need to be careful and know exactly which is which.